# Why it is not possible to have something like Cassandra with RDBMS/SQL style tables?

Tags: sql, nosql, cassandra, rdbms

I believe CAP theorem does not prevent this...

Comment: And what exactly is "something like Cassandra" - remember not everyone is using that thing.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is essentially a key-value store. (Keys map to multiple values.) The CAP theorem says that a distributed computer system can simultaneously provide only two of these three: consistency, availability, and partition tolerance.

It's not clear what you think those two, independent and unrelated facts might have to do with SQL tables.

You can implement key-value semantics in SQL tables, but you'd no longer have a key-value store.

You can build a [distributed SQL dbms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts001.htm), and again you'd no longer have a key-value store.

You can build a distributed key-value store, but you'd no longer be based on the relational model, and it would no longer be SQL. (Eventual consistency is a real problem.)

Answer (score 0):

**How would that be different from a SQL server?**

Note that for SQL servers, the main focus is on consistency. In particular, SQL is usually associated with ACID properties, which is a rather strict form of consistency (as it includes isolation, atomicity etc.)

In typical SQL use cases, you want to guarantee data consistency by any means. A lot of the use cases for nosql databases do not require much consistency (in particular when they are largely read-only) or are okay with snapshot semantics (i.e. the data returned was correct at some earlier point in time).

Independent of that, some of the NoSQL databases have **matured to what is now sometimes called "NewSQL"**. They do allow more complex queries than querying by key, and support some in-server processing functionality, index structures etc. Maybe that is what you were looking for.